# How to make "myProc = procedure of object" deprecated?

Tags: delphi

I m under *Delphi Tokyo* release 2 and I have this declaration:

```
type 
  FIRMessagingConnectCompletion = procedure of object;
```

That I would flag as deprecated. I try like this:

```
type
  FIRMessagingConnectCompletion = procedure of object deprecated 'Please listen for the FIRMessagingConnectionStateChangedNotification NSNotification instead.';
```

But didn't work with error `"E1030 Invalid compiler directive: 'DEPRECATED'"`. What did I miss?

Comment: Another way might be emiting own `{$MESSAGE WARN}`. Though it is no good if one wanted to find specific warning types (because it's `W1054` class).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that this is not allowed by the compiler. But there is a workaround:

```
type
    TProc = procedure of object;
    TProc1 = TProc deprecated 'test';
```

**Update:**
As pointed in comennts will be better this variant

```pascal
type
    __InternalFakeProcType__ = procedure of object;
    TProc = __InternalFakeProcType__ deprecated 'test';
```

Comment: I'm not sure how does this work around since the compiler will not warn about any usage of TProc.

Comment: @Sertac: Then do: `TXyz345981345 = procedure of object; TProc = TXyz345981345 deprecated 'Use something else';`. People will use `TProc` and not the other one. <g>

Comment: @Rudy - That's surely better. Still, I'm not sure what people will do... The thing that you leave a workaround to your workaround means it's not a workaround at all.

Comment: Move the original TProc declaration into another unit (say UnitX). Then change the declaration to `TProc = UnitX.TProc deprecated 'test';`

Comment: @Rudy, of course, the name `TXyz345981345` is self explaining :) Yet, I would call it `TDeprecatedProc`, or `TProcDeprecated`. Still it's a good idea!

Comment: @Sertac: I tested it and indeed, you can't put deprecated on the first declaration. What about `__Proc__ = procedure of object; TProc = __Proc__ deprecated 'some message'`? To most people, that many underscores tell them that the identifier is something not meant to be used publicly.

Comment: @Victoria: See my reply to Sertac. Use many underscores to indicate it is something very private. <g>

Comment: Nah, I will go and use `__Proc__`, it is beautiful. <g>

Comment: @Sertac: but it is deprecated. <g>

Comment: Oh! I wish I knew it. <g> In any case in its current state this answer does not help a bit. I hope what @Rudy has commented is so obvious that people are upvoting that intent. -1 from me for now.

Comment: @Sertac Akyuz As a rule, not one language can not give people what they need. In addition, compilers have bugs. But this is not a reason not to do anything at all. My decision is certainly not perfect, but it gives at least some way to solve the problem.

Comment: @Vasek - I don't see a solution. As I said, the compiler does not warn about TProc usage with what you have in the answer.